# Looking for op amps alternatives for Pico-Amps pA4-00125-76

Tags: amplifier

I am trying to read photodiode for a certain purpose.

As I am unfamiliar with electronics, I have read some papers. And one of papers said `Pico-Amps pA4-00125-76`. But I couldn't find information about that amplifier.

Currently I am thinking about using `SSC P4` as light source and Hamamatsu `S6036 PIN` diode as sensor. And as an amplifier, I will use `NE5532P from TI`.

Since there is no information about `pA4`,
I cannot figure out how `pA4` and `NE5532P` are different or similar.
(Actually, I saw a picture of `pAx` series. and it seems totally different with `NE5532P`.
Thus, I am worried that I've picked a wrong amplifier)

Could you give me an information about `pA4`?
Or, will `NE5532P` operate well with my circuit?
In my circuit, ADC after amplifier can accept +/- 3V.
Current is unknown (I will check for it.) And amplifier can process signal with bandwidth from 100 kHz up to 8 MHz.
Alternatively, could you suggest another amplifier that fits for my case?

If there isn't enought information given, please let me know it.

Comment: This isn't exactly a trivial thing to put together. You're easily talking about an order-of-GHz GBW for the transimpedance stage. Likely it needs to be a two- or three-stage design with a rather low transimpedance on the first stage. The circuit's performance is *critically dependent* on parasitics in the first stage, and you'll need a solid backplane to solder everything on, with rather short connections. You'll need shielding between the TIA and 2nd stage. Parasitic capacitance on the inverting input is very critical and must be kept low.

Answer (score 1):

Well a lot depends on your light level.  But in general I'd use a FET input opamp for photodiode circuits.  The [NE5532](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532.pdf) has a lot of input bias current.  This could lead to large DC offsets.  There are a number of better FET input opamps.  (I use a lot of opa134's for instance.)

Comment: Oh, it looks very similar to NE5532. But input bias current is about 5 pA. It sounds great. Then, only one thing remains. 'pA4' looks like [this](http://www.picoamps.de/microwave/img/pa_total_150.jpg). How are 'TI's op' amp and that 'pA4' thing different? Is it just for easy connectivity and some shielding?

Comment: @Jeon,  The PA4 looks like a microwave amp.  I've use that type of amp for very fast photodiode circiuts... ~100 MHz.  What are you trying to do?  The "classic" opamp photodiode circuit is the TIA amp.  (reverse bias the PD for more speed.)

Comment: I don't need such a fast op amp. I just need op amp for ~ 8 MHz. Detail is complicated, but the point is, I'd like to receive square-like signal (On-Off Keying) whose bandwidth does not exceed 8 MHz.

Comment: @Jeon Well you'll need to do a bunch of reading about TIA opamp circuits.  Your bandwidth depends on a lot of things... but the most important is how much light you have.. this determines what value of resistor you need in the TIA.. and then the opamp GBW and PD capacitance sets your bandwidth.  Unless you have a lot of light you won't get 8 MHz.  (As a rough guess that the RC corner frequency of the  sense (feed back resistor) and the photodiode capacitance.

Answer (score 1):

As @GeorgeHerold implied in the above comment, if you need 8MHz you may well require an op-amp with GBW in the hundreds of MHz.

\$f_{-3dB} \approx \frac {\sqrt {f_{RC} GBW}}{2}\$

where R is the feedback resistor (less resistance means less sensitivity)

and C is the input capacitance of the op-amp plus the PD capacitance under bias